# How to correctly build an Angular 6 app with i18n into "locale directories" with baseHref?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular6, locale

I'm trying to make my app available in multiple languages and I'm following Angular's [i18n guide](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). The default locale is `en-US` and there is also a French `fr` and a Spanish `es` translation.

This works fine, when running the app using `ng serve --configuration=fr` for example.

Now I'm at the point, where I want to build the app. I'm using this command:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --i18n-file src/locale/messages.es.xlf --i18n-format xlf --i18n-locale es
```

And I've updated `angular.json` like explained in the guide as well:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true
      },
      "es": {
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "dist/myapp/es",
        "baseHref": "/es/",
        "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
        "i18nFormat": "xlf",
        "i18nLocale": "es",
        "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
      },
      "fr": {
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "dist/myapp/fr",
        "baseHref": "/fr/",
        "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
        "i18nFormat": "xlf",
        "i18nLocale": "fr",
        "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
    }
  }
},
```

---

The build process works, and I get a translated version of the app.

---

Unfortunately, a few things don't work:

**1.)**
The app is always build into `dist/myapp` and not in `dist/myapp/fr` or `dist/myapp/es`.

**2.)**
The `baseHref`-parameter is not used, so I can't simply move the build into a subdirectory, like `/dist/myapp/fr`.

To make it more clear, after running `build` I want a folder structure like this:

```
/dist/myapp/en
/dist/myapp/fr
/dist/myapp/es
```

And when `myapp` is my webroot, it should be possible to access these routes in the browser:

```
/en
/fr
/es
```

**3.)**
Finally the `lang`-attribute ist not set correctly. `index.html` is not changed, an will always show:

```
<html lang="en">
```

instead of `<html lang="es">` or  `<html lang="fr">`.

---

What is missing to make this work correctly?

Comment: Do you pass the correct configuration when building? For instance, `ng build --configuration=es` to build the spanish version?

Comment: I used the build command as decribed [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#build-for-multiple-locales). There's no configuraion passed in the examples during build. Thanks for your help. @David

Comment: So does it work when you pass the configuration as in my previous comment?

Comment: This looks promising. Now I get the app deployed into a directory like `/fr` and it seems to work from that subdirectory. Unfortunatley, the app is now 4 MB insteads of 400 kB - do I need to copy all settings from the `prod` configuration into the locale configurations? This look error-prone, when you have to update all configurations, after changing one paramater in the build settings. Also the `lang`-attribute isn't changed. It's still `en`. But it's a good start. Thanks @David

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the correct configuration when doing the build. Otherwise, it'll just use the `production` configuration

You'll actually need to do one build for each language.

```
ng build --configuration=fr
ng build --configuration=en
ng build --configuration=es
```

You can either specify for each configuration which options to use (aot, output hashing,...) or you could put it in the `options` setting inside the `build`

```
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
     "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true
    },
```

As for changing the `lang` attribute, according to this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8102), you have to do it manually

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) doc: Document, @Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string, renderer: Renderer2) {
    renderer.setAttribute(doc.documentElement, 'lang', locale);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for the tip with the `lang`-attribute and the `options`-section in in the build configuration.